# Making Auth Dialog less intimidating

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-authentication

We're using Facebook as our exclusive login method, and we've had endless reports of the auth dialog box freaking people out.

We don't collect anything but name, email, and photo. The only special permission we request is email, but the basic "Includes name, profile picture, gender, networks, user ID, list of friends, and any other information I've made public" raises a lot of eyebrows for people.

Is there any way to pass some sort of "We promise not to be evil" message into that dialog box as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.  In your app settings you can customize the auth dialog with custom text to tell people what your app is doing. It's in `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{your app id}/auth`

Answer (score 1):

You could switch over to the new Auth Dialog? (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/authentication/)

Its a lot more friendlier looking and allows you to customize some of the text as well as set an explanation paragraph for extending permissions so you can write your 'we wont do evil' comment ;)